# How to resolve issue with gcc internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I have written a "hello world" C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

When running the below command:

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

I am getting below error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 }
 ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Below is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

gcc version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

### Edit

I compiled the code with `g++`:

```
g++ main.c -o main
```

and it worked fine with no errors.

Comment: Congratulation! You have found an error in your GCC installation. It can be as simple as a compromised file or a defective file system. Anyway, are you able to upgrade to a current OS and a current GCC?

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry didn't get you. I cannot upgrade current OS but can upgrade GCC. If you can please share the command to upgrade it.

Comment: See the documentation of your OS. You might want to re-install GCC, alternatively, to exclude defects in your file system. -- Why are you fixed to this old OS? -  Apparently you are cross-compiling with a third-party GCC. Have you tried other versions? Did the compiler work before or is this your first try? -- Please add all information to your question by [editing] it. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

Given your GCC version of `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` this is an Ubuntu problem.  [Ubuntu 18.04 was released 4 1/2 years ago](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), and the odds of this being a problem with GCC itself are rather slim.  As @thebusybee noted in the comments, this is almost certainly something caused by some problem with the compiler installation.

What you need to do is find out what's wrong with your Ubuntu GCC installation. First, make sure you're not doing something that causes the problem.  Environment variables such as `LD_PRELOAD` (or any of the `LD_*` envvals) can effect GCC. [There's also many other envvals that can](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).

Since you post that you can't upgrade the OS, that implies you're working in an organization with separate system administrator(s) that control the OS installation.  So if GCC's failing is not caused by something you're doing this is really the system administrators' problem to solve. If your organization gives them control of the OS installation, that includes everything that they control and you're unable to change, such as the OS-supplied GCC installation here.

What you can do to keep working:

- First, make sure you're not doing something to cause the problem

  - Check your environment for any `LD_*` envvals such as `LD_PRELOAD`.  Make sure they're not causing the problem.
  - Check for [other envvals that could effect GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).
- Install a version of GCC somewhere you **are** allowed to modify,
  such as your home directory

  - Modify your `PATH` and other necessary envvals to used your local GCC copy
- Use your organization's process(es) to create a trouble ticket to have your system administrator(s) investigate and repair your system.  If you're not allowed to modify it, it's **their** problem.
- If you have the time, you add something like the `-v` verbose flag or use [GCC's Developer Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options) such as `-freport-bug` to try to figure out what's wrong with your system and help your system administrator(s) in solving the real problem here.

Comment: A quick web research seems to reveal that this compiler is a third-party product.

Comment: @thebusybee Still, I can't see how any non-corrupted GCC install would `SIGSEGV` on the posted "Hello world" source code.  I'd definitely be spending a lot of time first making sure I'm not doing something to break the compiler, and *then* making sure the entire system is OK before submitting a bug report for something like this.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but "_this is a Ubuntu problem_" sounds a bit, er, narrow? As my comments above show, a bug report is not my first suggestion, actually none at all. Anyway, there are some simple questions still open to be answered by the OP. Most importantly whether this installation had worked at least once... ;-)